# Centered text results in underfull \hbox

Tags: boxes

```
\documentclass[version=last, paper=A4, DIV=12]{scrartcl}
\directlua{pdf.setminorversion(7)}

%
% Packages
%

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[final, babel]{microtype}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[unicode, breaklinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{addmargin}{.1\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \bfseries\LARGE Dario Gjorgjevski
  \end{center}
  \begin{flushleft}
    \begin{description}[itemsep=.1em, leftmargin=*]
    \item[\faStackExchange] \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/63447/d125q}
    \end{description}
  \end{flushleft}
\end{addmargin}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Why does this result in an underfull `\hbox`?  TeX shouldn't really try to stretch the centered text, should it?  The exact line from the log is:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 20--21
 []\TU/lmr/bx/n/17.28 Dario Gjorgjevski
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have

```
\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}
```

so redefined `\begin{center}` to use the package's `\Centering` command rather than `\centering`. This means that there is only finite stretch on each side, and in this case, not enough.

Generally I'd avoid that option.